# Azure CosmosDb shows Cancelled actions in AppInsights

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

From time to time, I see this error in Application Insights in Failures => failed dependencies :
[image: Azure exception screenshot]

Been searching through the documentation, but cannot see this mentioned anywhere. Does this status mean that the operation was cancelled through the token, or is it similar to the cross-partition response that used to be an 400 error? (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/606#issuecomment-427909582)

Also, will this action be retried or is there loss of data for this?

Comment: *Does this status mean that the operation was cancelled through the token*: Most likely. If you pass cancellation tokens that can happen. What type of app are we talking about? Web app? And if so, what tokens do you pass?

Comment: *Also, will this action be retried or is there loss of data for this?*: afaik they are not retried (cancellation is not a transient failure). If a write operation is cancelled then the data isn't written.

Comment: We're using Azure Functions, using the Cosmos SDK inside MediatR calls. They provide cancelation tokens, but we're not supplying them to all of the calls of CosmosDb (missed some places). As far as I can see, all of the failed calls are data retrieval. Happens randomly, around once in half an hour to once an hour, in different places, so there is no concrete pattern to it.

Comment: As far as you can tell, are those cancelled calls the ones that you pass a token to?

Comment: They are the ones i do not pass cancellation token to, which confused me the most